# JQuery reset the z-index of all of other children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I'm trying to make the element that been created dynamically to be on top of other elements once on click as shown below:

```
$("#clicks").on('click', '[id^=pin]', function (e) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $("#clicks").children('.pin').length;$i++){
                if ('pin' + $i == this.id) {
                    $(this).css({ 'z-index': '9999' });
                } else {
                    //How to set reset the z-index of other elements?
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of `z-index` is `auto`, however you can simplify your code massively to remove the loop:

```
$("#clicks").on('click', '[id^=pin]', function (e) {
    $("#clicks .pin").css('z-index', 'auto'); // reset zIndex on all .pin elements
    $(this).css('z-index', 9999);             // set the clicked pin to the top
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#clicks").on('click', '[id^=pin]', function (e) {
    $('[id^=pin]').css('z-index', '0'); //set z-index to all elements here
    $(this).css('z-index', '9999');
});
```